# Network Service Account password

Tags: networking, passwords, services, sql-server

In order to debug a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure, I would like to change the account that the SQL Server (MSSQLSrver) service is running under, namely, changing the account from "Network Service" to my current user account.

However, if something goes wrong, I would like to be able to change it back and I am concerned that since  this is a built in account for which I never knew the password, that I will not be able to set it back w/o knowing what the password is.

Will this be an issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to change it back by going in to Service Properties and changing "Log on as" to "NETWORK SERVICE" (use "Browse" and it should populate the password fields for you).

[image]

Comment: Hm, don't know why but this didn't work for me. The password fields are being filled in, but when trying to save the changes I get a dialog saying `Please enter a valid password`. Any clues?

Comment: You have to clear the password fields and it will enter them automatically when you click ok.

Answer (score 10):

To change it back enter for the field **This account**: `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService`,
then clear the password (suggested with dots) and select OK.

Now you can start the service again.